# PHP PDF Creation, EZPDF Class: table with just one line and row

Tags: php, pdf, border

This code:

```
$data = array(array('row1'=>'row2'));

$this->ezTable($data, null, '',
                array('width'=>'460', 'fontSize'=>'8', 'showLines'=>'1'));
```

shows a table with 2 rows and one column.

I need a table with just one row and one column, or four borders (top, bottom, right and left) around a text.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->ezTable($data, null, '',
                array('width'=>'460', 'fontSize'=>'8', 'showLines'=>'1','showHeadings'=>0));
```